# Django device tags

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to have functionality on my edit_project page where, when the page loads the current device tag is pre selected from the options menu so that a user 1 knows what the current tag is for that device but also so that if the click save/update the tag will remain as whatever is was.

at the moment when the page loads the initial state of the tag menu is "None" or blank if i remove the initial state from the forms function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8XSt.png)

i am able to display the current tag on my dashboard page no problem,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot5q9.png)

here are my current files:

Views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import models, transaction
from .models import DeviceInformation, Projects, ApiTokens
from .forms import ProjectForm
from django.db.models import Count, ExpressionWrapper, F, FloatField

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def dashboard(request):
    devices = get_devices_without_project()
    projects = get_queryset('Projects')
    tokens = get_queryset('ApiTokens')
    context = {'devices': devices, 'projects': projects, 'tokens': tokens}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)

def get_devices_without_project():
    return DeviceInformation.objects.filter(projects__isnull=True)

def get_queryset(model):
    if model == 'Projects':
        return Projects.objects.all()
    elif model == 'ApiTokens':
        return ApiTokens.objects.all()


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def create_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                project = form.save(commit=False)
                project.save()

                # Explicitly set many-to-many relationships after saving the project
                device_ids = request.POST.getlist('devices')
                devices = DeviceInformation.objects.filter(id__in=device_ids)
                project.devices.set(devices)

                # Set tokens after saving the project (if applicable)
                token_ids = request.POST.getlist('tokens')
                tokens = ApiTokens.objects.filter(id__in=token_ids)
                project.tokens.set(tokens)

                # Update app_name for associated devices using the selected token
                for device in devices:
                    device.app_name = tokens.first().token_name if tokens.exists() else project.proj_name
                    device.save()

                # Set tags after saving the project
                project_tags = request.POST.getlist('tags')
                for device, tag in zip(devices, project_tags):
                    device.tags = tag
                    device.save()

            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/create-project.html', context)


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def edit_project(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Projects, id=project_id)

    # Get the current tags for each device associated with the project
    current_device_tags = {device.id: device.tags for device in project.devices.all()}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                # Save the project
                form.save()

                # Update app_name for associated devices using the selected token
                device_ids = request.POST.getlist('devices')
                devices = DeviceInformation.objects.filter(id__in=device_ids)
                tokens = project.tokens.all()

                for device in devices:
                    device.app_name = tokens.first().token_name if tokens.exists() else project.proj_name
                    device.save()

                # Set tags after saving the project
                project_tags = request.POST.getlist('tags')

                # Update the tags for each device if changes are made
                for device, tag in zip(devices, project_tags):
                    if tag != current_device_tags.get(device.id, ''):
                        device.tags = tag
                        device.save()

            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(instance=project)

    context = {'form': form, 'project': project}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/edit_project.html', context)


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def delete_project(request, project_id):
    """
    View function for deleting a project.

    Handles the form submission for deletion confirmation
    and deletes the project.
    Redirects to the dashboard upon successful deletion.
    """
    project = get_object_or_404(Projects, id=project_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check if the user confirmed the deletion
        if 'confirm_delete' in request.POST:
            project.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'Project deleted successfully.')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            # If not confirmed, redirect back to the project list
            return redirect('delete_project', project_id=project.id)

    context = {'project': project}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/delete_project.html', context)

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def confirm_delete_project(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Projects, id=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project.delete()
        return redirect('dashboard')
    context = {'project': project}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/delete_project.html', context)

def api_tokens(request):
    # Retrieve all ApiTokens along with the count of connected devices for each token
    api_tokens_with_device_count = ApiTokens.objects.annotate(
        device_count=Count('projects__devices')
    ).filter(device_count__lte=50)

    # Calculate progress for each token
    for api_token in api_tokens_with_device_count:
        if api_token.device_limit > 0:
            api_token.progress = (api_token.device_count / api_token.device_limit) * 100
        else:
            api_token.progress = 0

    context = {'api_tokens_with_device_count': api_tokens_with_device_count}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/api-tokens.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

PROFILE_CHOICES = (
    ('ClassA-OTAA', 'Class-A'),
    ('ClassB-OTAA', 'Class-B'),
    ('ClassC-OTAA', 'Class-C'),
    ('ClassCB-OTAA', 'Class-CB'),
)

TAG_CHOICES = (
    ('Com', 'Commissioned'),
    ('UnCom', 'Uncommissioned'),
    ('DeCom', 'Decommissioned'),
    ('None', 'None'),
)

class DeviceInformation(models.Model):
    dev_name = models.CharField(('Name'), max_length=20)
    deveui = models.CharField(('Deveui'), max_length=20)
    dev_prof = models.CharField(('Device Profile'), max_length=12, choices=PROFILE_CHOICES, default='ClassCB-OTAA')
    app_name = models.CharField(('Application Name'), max_length=20)
    app_key = models.CharField(('Application Key'), max_length=32)
    is_assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.CharField(('Tags'), max_length=10, choices=TAG_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_name


class ApiTokens(models.Model):
    token_name = models.CharField(('Token Name'), max_length=20)
    full_token_name = models.CharField(('Full Name'), max_length=32, default=None)
    device_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(('Device Limit'), default=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.token_name

class Projects(models.Model):
    proj_name = models.CharField(('Project Name'), max_length=50)
    notes = models.CharField(('Notes'), max_length=250)
    tokens = models.ManyToManyField(ApiTokens, verbose_name=('Tokens'), related_name='projects')
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(DeviceInformation, blank=True, related_name='projects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proj_name
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for device in self.devices.all():
            device.app_name = "none"
            device.save()

        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py:

```
# dashboard/forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Projects, ApiTokens, DeviceInformation, TAG_CHOICES

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ['proj_name', 'notes', 'tokens', 'devices']
        widgets = {
            'devices': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'tokens': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 5}),
        }

    devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DeviceInformation.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False
    )

    tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=TAG_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=False,
        initial=['None']  # Initial value as a list
    )

    available_devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DeviceInformation.objects.filter(projects__isnull=True),
        required=False
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # You can further customize the label or help_text if needed
        self.fields['devices'].label = 'Assigned Devices'
        self.fields['devices'].help_text = 'Devices already assigned to the project.'
```

edit_project.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Edit Project</h2>

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'edit_project' project.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="{{ form.proj_name.id_for_label }}">Project Name:</label>
    {{ form.proj_name }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.notes.id_for_label }}">Notes:</label>
    {{ form.notes }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.tokens.id_for_label }}">Tokens:</label>
    {{ form.tokens }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.devices.id_for_label }}">Assigned Devices:</label>
    <br>
    {% for device_form in form.devices %}
      <div>
        {{ device_form }}
        <br>
        <label for="{{ form.tags.id_for_label }}">Status:</label>
        {{ form.tags }}
        <br>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <hr>  <!-- Add a horizontal line to separate assigned and available devices -->

    <label for="{{ form.available_devices.id_for_label }}">Available Devices:</label>
    <br>
    {% for device_form in form.available_devices %}
      <div>
        {{ device_form }}
        <label for="{{ device_form.id_for_label }}"></label>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Update Project</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

create-project.hmtl:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Create Project</h2>

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'create_project' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <label for="{{ form.proj_name.id_for_label }}">Project Name:</label>
    {{ form.proj_name }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.notes.id_for_label }}">Notes:</label>
    {{ form.notes }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.tokens.id_for_label }}">Tokens:</label>
    {{ form.tokens }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.devices.id_for_label }}">Devices:</label>
    <br>
    {% for device_form in form.devices %}
      <div>
        {{ device_form }}
        <br>
        <label for="{{ form.tags.id_for_label }}">Tags:</label>
        {{ form.tags }}
        <br>        
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Create Project</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Devices</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for device in devices %}
      <li>{{ device.dev_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <h2>Projects</h2>
  {% for project in projects %}
    <h3>{{ project.proj_name }}</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="150px">Device Name</th>
          <th width="200px">Device EUI</th>
          <th width="150px">Device Profile</th>
          <th width="200px">Application Name</th>
          <th width="350px">Application Key</th>
          <th width="200px">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for device in project.devices.all %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ device.dev_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.deveui }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.dev_prof }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.app_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.app_key }}</td>
            <td>{{ device.tags }}</td>  {# Display the device tag here #}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_project' project.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit">Delete Project</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'edit_project' project.id %}"><button>Edit</button></a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Ive tried changing the edit_project template and the **init** in the forms but then the tag option menus no longer load like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhsu8.png)

or if i adjust the view to try get the current tag to render nothing changes.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).